# Loop printing first word only

Tags: java

I'm working on a program for software testing class.  I need to create a loop that iterates over a string in order to find a particular word and then compare it to the expected result. The problem I'm having is that my loop only prints out the first word of the string. I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
String input = "Now is the time for all great men to come to the aid of their country";
String tempString = "";
char c = '\0';
int n = input.length();
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    if(c != ' ')
    {
        c = input.charAt(i);
        tempString = tempString + c;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(tempString);
        tempString = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is only printing out the first word is that once a space is found you don't ever reset the value of c so the if will always be false and will print out tempString which you have set to the empty string.

To fix the code as you have written:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Now is the time for all great men to come to the aid of their country";
    String tempString = "";
    char c = '\0';
    int n = input.length();
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        c = input.charAt(i); // this needs to be outside the if statement
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            tempString = tempString + c;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(tempString);
            tempString = "";
        }
    }
}
```

But ... it's a lot cleaner to simply use the built in string methods to do what you want (e.g. split out on spaces). You can also simply use a for each loop since the split method returns a string array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Now is the time for all great men to come to the aid of their country";
    for (String word : input.split(" ")) {
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move setting of `c` *outside* the `if`. Otherwise, you compare the *prior* character, rather than comparing the current one.

```
c = input.charAt(i); // <<== Move outside "if"
if(c != ' ')
{
    tempString = tempString + c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using `split` instead

```
 String input = "Now is the time for all great men to come to the aid of their country";

 String arr[] = input.split (" ");

 for (int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    System.out.println (arr[x]);  // each word - do want you want 
 }
```